# My app does not appear in the iOS notification center - Appcelerator

Tags: ios, xcode, apple-push-notifications, titanium, appcelerator

I'm having serious headaches with push for iOS with titanium appcelerator.

I generated several versions in testflight, but none of them appear in the iOS notification center, however, when I swipe directly into the device, it works normally on my iPad Mini.

I am currently using these settings:

```
Operating System
  Name                        = Mac OS X
  Version                     = 10.12

  Architecture                = 64bit
  # CPUs                      = 4
  Memory                      = 4294967296

Node.js
  Node.js Version             = 4.6.0
  npm Version                 = 2.15.9

Titanium CLI
  CLI Version                 = 5.0.9

Titanium SDK
  SDK Version                 = 5.5.1.GA
  SDK Path                    = /Users/silvio/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/5.5.1.GA
  Target Platform             = iphone
```

**Xcode Version**: 8.2 (8C38)

My code in Alloy.js:

```
if (Ti.Platform.name === 'android') {
  // set android-only options
  var pnOptions = {
    senderId: 'xxxx', // It's the same as your project id
    notificationSettings: {
      sound: 'mysound.mp3', // Place soudn file in platform/android/res/raw/mysound.mp3
      smallIcon: 'appicon.png', // Place icon in platform/android/res/drawable/notification_icon.png
      largeIcon: 'appicon.png', // Same
      vibrate: true, // Whether the phone should vibrate
      insistent: true, // Whether the notification should be insistent
      group: 'Edufy', // Name of group to group similar notifications together
      localOnly: false, // Whether this notification should be bridged to other devices
      priority: 2 // Notification priority, from -2 to 2
    }
  };

} else { // set ios-only options.
  // Sets interactive notifications as well if iOS8 and above. Interactive notifications is optional.
  if (parseInt(Ti.Platform.version.split(".")[0], 10) >= 8) {
    var thumbUpAction = Ti.App.iOS.createUserNotificationAction({
      identifier: "THUMBUP_IDENTIFIER",
      title: "Aceitar",
      activationMode: Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_ACTIVATION_MODE_BACKGROUND,
      destructive: false,
      authenticationRequired: false
    });

    var thumbDownAction = Ti.App.iOS.createUserNotificationAction({
      identifier: "THUMBDOWN_IDENTIFIER",
      title: "Regeitar",
      activationMode: Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_ACTIVATION_MODE_BACKGROUND,
      destructive: false,
      authenticationRequired: false
    });

    var thumbUpDownCategory = Ti.App.iOS.createUserNotificationCategory({
      identifier: "THUMBUPDOWN_CATEGORY",
      // The following actions will be displayed for an alert dialog
      actionsForDefaultContext: [thumbUpAction, thumbDownAction],
      // The following actions will be displayed for all other notifications
      actionsForMinimalContext: [thumbUpAction, thumbDownAction]
    });

    var pnOptions = {
      types: [Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT, Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SOUND],
      categories: [thumbUpDownCategory]
    };
  } else { //No support for interactive notifications, omit categories
    var pnOptions = {
      types: [Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_ALERT, Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_SOUND]
    };
  }
}

// set cross-platform event
var onReceive = function(event) {};

// Create instance with base url
var tiPush = require('ti-push-notification').init({
  backendUrl: "http://xxxx.com.br/painel/ws/push_test.php"
});

// register this device
tiPush.registerDevice({
  pnOptions: pnOptions,
  onReceive: onReceive,
  extraOptions: {
    action: 'register',
    user_id: 123
  }
});
```

My certificates in the apple store are all valid, as in the prints below:

Push Notifications Enabled:

[image]

Certificates:

[image]

Prov Profiles:

[image]

Also, I tried adding the Entitlements.plist in these locations:

- Project / Entitlements.plist
- Project / app / Entitlements.plist
- Project / app / platform / ios / Entitlements.plist
- Project / app / platform / ios /  .plist

I also added the lines from within the  tag to tiapp.xml, but it did not work ... below the Entitlements.plist code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>aps-environment</key>
    <string>development</string> <!-- Either development or production -->
    <key>application-identifier</key>
    <string>xxxx.com.colegiokennedy</string>
    <key>keychain-access-groups</key>
    <array>
      <string>xxx.com.colegiokennedy</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I've also tried changing the development environment to production, but it did not work too.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try including **Ti.App.iOS.USER_NOTIFICATION_TYPE_BADGE**.

Make sure that in your iOS device, go to **Settings -> Notifications -> Your_App -> Show in Notification Centre** is selected. You can check that what kind of settings are on/off for your app's notifications.